# Firebase Cloud Functions: Upload files using storage putString

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-storage

Is it possible to upload files using cloud functions? This is my attempt:

```
const firebase = require("firebase");
app.post('/images', async function (request, response) {
  const data = request.body;
  var file = data.image; // base64 image data
  const storageRef = firebase.storage().ref(`images/${data.name}`);

  storageRef.putString(file, 'data_url').then(function (snapshot) {
    response.send('success')
  });
})
```

and I'm getting error `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: firebase.storage is not a function` is there any example that I can find?

Comment: What does your package.json look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. In a Cloud Function, generally you should be using the [Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/admin/start) (`firebase-admin` not `firebase`). Note that the Admin SDK bypasses security rules, so you should make sure to handle authorization for uploading properly.

In a broader sense, however, I don't think this is actually what you probably want to do. Cloud Functions have relatively low limits on request size (10MB) and you have to pay for the compute time during the upload. Instead, why not just use the JS SDK in the application itself? Your users can still upload directly into the Cloud Storage bucket, but without incurring the extra cost of running through a function first.